# Adding material to spheres sequentially using Python

Tags: python

I have the following script, which I was hoping would add a basic red material to my spheres as they are sequentially created. Unfortunately, the script does not work, in the sense that no material is added to any sphere. Indeed, no spheres are created, but in the absence of "bpy.ops.material.new()" and "bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0)", the script produces spheres.

Could someone please help me tweak the script to make it function as desired?

```
import bpy, csv
fp = "C:/Blender/Spheres.csv"
with open( fp ) as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for i, row in enumerate( rdr ):
        if i == 0: continue # Skip column title
        # Generate UV sphere at x = row0, y = row1, z = row2, and radius = row3.
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size = float(row[3]), location = float(row[0]),float(row[1]),float(row[2])))
        bpy.ops.material.new()
        bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0)
```

A snippet of my CSV. spheres.csv

```
x;y;z;r
2.34;2.45;7.65;0.024
6.78;9.31;6.33;0.0467
3.36;8;1.04;0.3626
```

Comment: You don't give us any information what "it does not work" means. You may also want to reduce your script to the bare minimum (I doubt that running `meters.py` is realy required) so that we don't have to investigate unnecessary code.

Comment: @dr. Sybren, I have ammended the question to address your comment. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share (the first three lines of) your CSV file too? Since you say no sphere is created, maybe it never reaches the sphere creation operator?

Comment: @ dr. Sybren. I have added a link to my CSV.

Comment: Don't link to the file (Dropbox links will go away, it's horrible for archival purposes), just paste the first few lines into the question, like you did with the script. You also may want to change your username from 'user120xxxx' to something more personal.

Comment: @ dr. Sybren. I have added a snippet instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since each sphere's material gets the same properties, I think it's a shame to create a new material for each sphere. Here's my solution, which:

- Doesn't use an operator to create a new material, but rather calls a regular function `bpy.data.materials.new()`. This is faster, doesn't create unnecessary undo steps, and directly returns the material;
- Uses `next(rdr)` to skip the first row, rather than using `enumerate` and checking the index each and every iteration;
- Uses `bpy.path.abspath` to convert a blendfile-relative path to an absolute path that Python understands;
- Separates data conversion from the strings obtained by the CSV reader to the floats you need for Blender;
- Uses slice notation to shorten the `b.o.m.primitive_uv_sphere_add` call;
- Follows PEP-8 for readability.

---

```
import csv

import bpy

# Create the material
try:
    mat = bpy.data.materials['Sphere']
except KeyError:
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new('Sphere')
mat.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0)

fp = "//spheres.csv"
with open(bpy.path.abspath(fp)) as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    next(rdr)  # Skip column title
    for row in rdr:
        # Generate UV sphere at x = row0, y = row1, z = row2, and radius = row3.
        data = [float(x) for x in row]    
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=data[0:3], size=data[3])
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
        bpy.context.object.material_slots[0].material = mat
```

Answer (score 0):

A little correction: 
add a parenthesis *'('* 
add linkage code

```
import bpy, csv
#fp = "C:/Blender/Spheres.csv"
fp = "C:/temp/Spheres.csv"
with open( fp ) as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for i, row in enumerate( rdr ):
        if i == 0: continue # Skip column title
        # Generate UV sphere at x = row0, y = row1, z = row2, and radius = row3.
        # add '('
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(
                    size = float(row[3]), 
                    location = (float(row[0]),float(row[1]),float(row[2]))
                )
        bpy.ops.material.new()
        # add linkage
        bpy.context.object.active_material = bpy.data.materials[-1]
        bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Don't use operators where it isn't necessary. `bpy.ops.material.new()` can be replaced by `mat = bpy.data.materials.new('Sphere')`, which is faster and doesn't make you guess that it's `bpy.data.materials[-1]`.